# Maven can't resolve any Java import statements

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Now I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Community Edition) with Maven 3.6.1., JDK 1.8.0_131 at a laptop with Windows 10.

I imported the project from GitHub, that 100% works at other PCs.
For the unknown reason can't resolve any import:
[image: imports view]
When I trying import any class I receive a message like `Cannot resolve symbol 'WebDriver'`.
The same situation was with a project created from scratch.
I tried to re-install IntelliJ IDEA (current and previous versions), Maven (current and previous), JDK (13). Also, I tried to delete `.M2 directory`, re-import Maven project but still had this issue.

When I tried to compile (or execute any commands, like "install", "deploy" etc.) project from Maven command line I received:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenResourcesFiltering was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo
1 error
```

Project JDK is set up properly.
Project's POM.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.udc</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-selenium-10.02.2020</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <serenity.version>2.1.6</serenity.version>
        <jbehave.version>1.46.0</jbehave.version>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>3.8.1</webdrivermanager.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.19</mysql.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <surefire.version>2.20</surefire.version>
        <source.encoding>UTF-8</source.encoding>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <test.name>*</test.name>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
            <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${source.encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/tests/**/${test.name}.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using web driver in test or main code

Comment: Yes, I'm using Selenium WebDriver

Comment: I mean, your `webDriverManeger` only exists in test phase with `<scope>test</scope>`. You may remove this line and give it a try. Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it doesn't help

Comment: Realy weird, webdrivermanager are designed to make webdriver accessiable. You may create a aissue on that project for help

Comment: The cause of problem isn't only webdrivermanager, it related to all import as minimum as selenium, junit, serenity improts (it can be visible from screenshot).